# Zeros of characteristic polynomial over field $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields

I need to find the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 \\
    2       & 3 & 3 \\
    1       & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}_5^{3 \times 3}.$$

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda) = 4 \lambda^3 + 4 \lambda^2 + 2$.

I calculated $p(0) = 2, \  p(1) = 0,\ p(2) = 0,\ p(3) = 1,\ p(4) = 2$ and $p'(1) = 0$, which means that $\lambda_{1,2} = 1$ and $\lambda_3 = 2$.

Is this correct and is there a better way to calculate eigenvalues of matrices over finite fields? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not to be nit picky but wouldn't the coefficient in front of the cubic term be have to  4 since $-1 \equiv 4 \mod 5$?

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen, since they represent the same element of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, you are free to choose one or the other. For instance, my choice would be to write the polynomial as $p(\lambda) = - \lambda^{3} - \lambda^{2} + 2$. Although you are right that one should use the same representation for all appearances of the same element.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: @curiouspigeon246 Your solution is correct, kudos.

Comment: @andreas-caranti Thank you.

Comment: $\lambda =1$ is obvious. From there I would continue with long division and Vieta.

Comment: @sassatelli-giulio Could you explain why that makes it more complicated, I don't really understand. Is it true that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $k$ iff it is a zero of all $p(t), p'(t), \ldots p^{(k-1)}(t)$, even if the field has a positive characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this equation is to observe that for all nonzero roots $\lambda^2\equiv\pm1\bmod 5$, from Fermat's Little Theorem. We substitute each possible value, solve the resulting linear equation, and check whether the roots match with the assumed value of $\lambda^2$.

With $\lambda^2\equiv1$ we obtain $\lambda^3\equiv\lambda$ and so

$4\lambda^3+4\lambda^2+2\equiv4\lambda+1.$

Thus $4\lambda+1\equiv0$ and $\lambda\equiv1$, which checks with the assumption $\lambda^2=1$. We also have the first and second derivatives at $\lambda\equiv1$:

$2\lambda^2+3\lambda\equiv0$

$4\lambda+3\equiv2,$

from which $\lambda\equiv1$ is a double root.

The reader can work out that the case $\lambda^2\equiv-1$ gives a root $\lambda\equiv2$ which again is consistent with the assumed squared value.